# Why Mongo TTL index is not been creating via Spring Data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, ttl

**Problem**: mongodb ttl index is not been creating via Spring Data

I have a spring-boot application and MongoDB as database.

I have an entity class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(COLLECTION_NAME)
public class PersonEntity {

    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "person_info";
    private static final String PERSON_NAME = "person_name";


    @Id
    private PersonId id;

    @Field(name = PERSON_NAME)
    private String personName;

    
    @Indexed(name = "ttl_index", expireAfterSeconds=20)
    private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

And I persist a new document to MongoDB using this repository:

```
public interface SellerRequestInfoRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<PersonEntityEntity, PersonId> {}
```

using

```
personRepository.save(entity);
```

But the TTL index is not created on MongoDB after insetting the Person document:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOupf.png)

Please, advice, what I am doing wrong

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I added more details to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cite the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#mapping.index-creation):

> Spring Data MongoDB can automatically create indexes for entity types annotated with @Document. Index creation must be explicitly enabled since version 3.0 to prevent undesired effects with collection lifecycle and performance impact.

Did you enable automatic index creation? Because if you didn't, that will most likely be the reason why your index was not created.

With Spring Boot you can enable automatic index creation with the following config in your `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      auto-index-creation: true
```

Or if you prefer properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I missed: the application.yaml config